# How to set LongListSelector.ItemSource by C# code like ItemsSource="{Binding CustomSounds.Items}"

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, longlistselector, itemsource

```
            <phone:LongListSelector 
                Margin="0,0,-12,0" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding CustomSounds.Items}"
                LayoutMode="Grid"
                GridCellSize="150,150"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CustomSoundTileDataTemplate}" 
                SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_SelectionChanged" 
                x:Name="CustomSoundLongListSelector"
                />
```

I have a LongListSelector like that, now i change something in CustomSounds.Items and want to reload it. How can i do that in code behind file, CustomSoundLongListSelector.ItemSource = ...

Comment: CustomSoundLongListSelector.ItemSource = CustomSounds.Items directly used it..or make your items collection a Observable Collections.

Answer (score 1):

You should do in the code-behind just this:

```
CustomSoundLongListSelector.ItemsSource = model.CustomSounds.Items;
```

Note the "model" is here the DataContext set on your page or more specifically on the LongListSelector.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your ViewModel to notify the view to reload your data. I think this is a pretty standard pattern in MVVM.

Essentially:

> public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
>
> ```
> //... your other VM stuff...
>
> public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
> private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
> {
>     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
>     if (null != handler)
>     {
>         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
>     }
> } }
> ```

And then when you change the Items, you say:

> NotifyPropertyChanged("Items");

Answer (score 0):

If you will use Observable collection for item source You do not have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` It will work on its own